# Material multiplication doesn't seem to work as i understand it

Tags: texturing, materials, mathematics

so i had assumed that when it comes to black and white textures, the fully black parts have the value of 0 and the white parts are 1 and everything else in the middle is 0-1. now have this bnw texture of a body which has 0.4 and 0.7 lightness value, the thing is when i multiply it by 4. i assumed the 0.4 parts would turn to 1.6 and the 0.7 parts would turn to 2.8. which should make those 2 parts of my textures completely white since it's equal to/more than 1. but when i tried it in blender, it simply isn't the case. am i misunderstanding how material multiplication or how the values are mapped or something?

Before multiplication:

[image]

After multiplication:

[image]